# How can I combine these tables to get the correct output?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, inner-join

I'm starting to learn sql queries and trying to figure out some more complex ones (for me).
As I have these tables and schemas:

Customer (CustomerID, name, address, age, balance)

Director (DirectorID, DirectorName, AwardWinner)

Movies (MovieID, title, DirectorID, rating, productionStudio, format, ProductionYear)

```
            DirectorID FK references director
```

Rented (CustomerID, movieID, Pickupdate, returnDate)

```
            CustomerID FK references Customer

            movieID FK references Movies
```

In Movies schema

```
      format could be ‘VHS’, ‘DVD’, ‘Blue Ray’.

      rating in movies could have values such as ‘PG’, ‘PG13’,’ R’… etc

      ProductionStudio could have values such as ‘Universal Studio’, ‘Disney’ …etc.
```

In Director schema

```
       awardWining has a value of 1 if the director won an award otherwise it will be 0.
```

I'm trying to figure out how to join them in order to figure out who rented more than 3 titles?

Comment: You would need to join `Customers` against `Rented`. Use `group by` and `having` to narrow to those with three or more. You could also use a correlated subquery but I gather that would be advanced for you at this point.

Comment: Build from `SELECT CustomerId FROM Rented GROUP BY CustomerId HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MovieId) > 3` as a subquery, joined to the rest. If renting the same movie 3 times counts as 3 rentals, remove DISTINCT

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts, you removed all particulars, I rolled that back, posts are for others forever. [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: that was an accident, I was trying to edit and i saved it without the info. I tried flagging the post to see if it can be restored. thank you. @philipxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation with group by and having clause

```
select c.CustomerID, c.name,count(title)
from Customer c inner join Rented r 
                on c.CustomerID=r.CustomerID
     inner join Movies m
                on r.movieID=m.movieID
group by c.CustomerID, c.name
having count(title)>=3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.CustomerId
from Customer c inner join Rented r on r.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
group by c.CustomerId
having count(*) > 3; -- use count(distinct r.MovieId) if repeated rentals is a concern
```

You don't appear to need anything from the `Movies` table so there's no reason to even join that. And supposing that you did, you'd generally want to count on an id column rather than something like `Title` where two different rows might actually have the same names.

Because of the way `group by` works you often use a dummy aggregate to return extra detail information:

```
select c.CustomerId. min(c.Name) as Name
from Customer c inner join Rented r on r.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
group by c.CustomerId;
```

An alternative to that is to avoid the aggregation step:

```
select *
from Customer
where (
    select count(*) from Rented r
    where r.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
) > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation and join

```
 SELECT r.CustomerId FROM Rented r
join Customer c on c.CustomerId=r.CustomerId
join Movies m on r.movieID= r.movieID
 GROUP BY r.CustomerId 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.title) > 3
```